# Accessing url of ImageField via values() method on django queryset

Tags: django, django-views, django-orm

I have a data model in Django where I save photos uploaded by users. There's an attribute called `image_file` in the `Photo` model (of the type `ImageField`) where - among other things - the image's url is stored. I can successfully access this url with `item.image_file.url` in the template (and view) for instance.

However, I can't seem to be able to do the following in the view:

`Photo.objects.filter(owner=user).order_by('-id').values('id','image_file.url')[:10]`

I.e. For a particular user, I'm trying to get the 10 latest photo objects' image urls along with object ids. This gives me `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'image_file.url' into field`. Shouldn't this have worked?

I understand I can retrieve the entire object and do the filtering in the template, but I felt it's more optimal to solely retrieve the fields I actually need instead of the full object.

p.s. it's a postgresql backend and the underlying Storage class has been over-ridden

Comment: The `url` is a `property`, not a value in the database ([FileField code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L61)) which is why you can't get to it from `values()`. As far as I can see, you'd have to get the url value separately...

Comment: That's what I'd do - you might want to take a look at [`only()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#only) though. If you go that route, you should probably watch the SQL queries with something like [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar). If the `url` property tries to retrieve a field that wasn't included in `only()`, it will likely make a separate SQL call.

Comment: Sure thing - and are you sure `only()` wouldn't give you the `id`? I don't recall trying that, but I don't see why it wouldn't be able to pull it. With `only()`, you don't lose the ability to access anything - you just incur another SQL hit if you didn't specify it.

Comment: @JensAstrup: checked it out. In principle you're right .only('id','image_file') does give me attribute retrieval - however as per the debug tool bar, I end up doing 3X more SQL queries than what I was originally doing (good call on profiling this). So the original approach you recommended still sticks. p.s. I realized I was confusing `only()` with `latest()` when I earlier said it won't give me `ids`. Brain's short circuited! Anywhoo, thanks for the assistance. Until next time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `url` is a `property`, not a value in the database ([FileField code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L61)) which is why you can't get to it from `values()`. As far as I can see, you'd have to get the `url` value separately...

You might want to take a look at `only()` though. If you go that route, you should probably watch the SQL queries with something like Django Debug Toolbar. If the `url` property tries to retrieve a field that wasn't included in `only()`, it will likely make a separate SQL call.